# Getting random end user from QuickBlox

Tags: objective-c, quickblox

I'm developing a social app. For current user, I need to randomly show other users of the app.

I first want to use this code to get the number of users:

```
PagedRequest *request = [PagedRequest new];
request.perPage = 1;
request.page = 1;
[QBUsers usersWithPagedRequest:request delegate:self.proxy];
```

I noticed that this is the XML returned:

```
<users type="array" current_page="1" per_page="1" total_entries="13">
  <user>
    <blob-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <created-at type="datetime">2013-07-24T06:16:13Z</created-at>
    <email>xxxxxx@xx.com</email>
    <external-user-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <facebook-id nil="true"/>
    <full-name>XXX xxx</full-name>
    <id type="integer">236286</id>
    <last-request-at type="datetime">2013-11-15T06:27:09Z</last-request-at>
    <login>t2wu</login>
    <owner-id type="integer">4282</owner-id>
    <phone nil="true"/>
    <twitter-id nil="true"/>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2013-11-15T06:27:09Z</updated-at>
    <website nil="true"/>
    <user-tags nil="true"/>
  </user>
</users>
```

My intention is to get the 13 from the "total_entries=13", so I know that the total number of users, then make a request like this again:

```
PagedRequest *request = [PagedRequest new];
request.perPage = 1;
request.page = [self randomAmong: 13];
[QBUsers usersWithPagedRequest:request delegate:self.proxy];
```

where `[self randomAmong: 13]` just pick one number out of 1 and 13, then grab the user's profile picture and show it to the current user.

Three questions:

1. Although I can see the number 13 in the XML in the console
   output, I have no idea how to get that number.
2. I only want to
   rotate through my mobile application users, not my developer's
   account (the account user). QuickBlox allows multiple applications
   associated with one QuickBlox account user; however, all users seems
   to be lumped together. Although I could make sure that I only have
   one application inside this account, I still need to be able to
   exclude myself from it.
3. This is a relatively minor question.
   Although the above attempt to get the current number of users is not
   an attempt to log in, the delegate method
   `-(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result` has result as a class
   of `QBUUserLogInResult`. I don't understand why it is, why isn't it
   `QBUUserPagedResult` or `QBUUserResult` which seems to make more
   sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a right way, here are the answers for your questions:

1)

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark QBActionStatusDelegate

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{ 

    // Get User result 
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserPagedResult class]]){
        QBUUserPagedResult *usersResult = (QBUUserPagedResult *)result; 

        int totalEntries = usersResult.totalEntries;
    }
}
```

2)

You can use tags to separate users. While user sign up - just add a tag to this user, for example 'app1'.

Next - to retrieve users with tag 'app1' - use the next query:

```
[QBUsers usersWithTags:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"app1", nil] delegate:self];
```

3)

User login query will return 'QBUUserLogInResult' result

Get single user query will return 'QBUUserResult' result

Get multiple users query will return 'QBUUserPagedResult' result

Comment: Oh tags, I forgot about that. Got it. As for #3, that doesn't look like what happened to me. I wasn't logging in and I got QBUUserLogInResult. But well, minor problem. Thanks a bunch. :)